# ordering in SQL subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Can someone tell me why this works

```
SELECT t.s from 
    (SELECT something AS s FROM SOMETABLE ORDER BY s) AS t
```

but this doesn't?

```
SELECT t.s from 
    (SELECT something AS s FROM SOMETABLE) AS t 
ORDER BY t.s
```

This is a piece of a solution to a challenge on a coding competition site. I got the answer right, through experimentation, but I'm not sure why one is valid and the other isn't.

Comment: This should work...[sqlfiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e62b9/1)

Comment: Both are valid Sir!

Comment: @Forward and [at]1000111 okay. i'll try both in the future on that site.